# Custom validation message will not be reset in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have written a custom validator with AngularJS to validate two form fields.

[image: form to start with]

- The first field has *required* validation.
- The second has *required* and *same* validation, the last one being the custom validation I try to achieve.

When I put something in the first password field, the second validates false, because it is empty. This is what I expect (the message saying that the field is required).

[image: message about required field validation error]

If I put something in the second password box that does not equal the first, the error message is also the expected one, saying that the fields do not match.

[image: Message saying that the fields do not match]

Now, if I clear the second field I get a validation error that I do not expect, how can I get the old one back? The message still sais that the fields do not match.

[image: Message still saying that the fields do not match]

javascript:

```
app.directive('same', function ()
{
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, mCtrl)
    {
      mCtrl.$parsers.push(function(value)
      {
        var prev = $(element[0]).parent().prev().find('input');
        var prev_value = prev.val();
        var is_valid = value == prev_value;

        mCtrl.$setValidity('same', is_valid);
        element[0].setCustomValidity(!is_valid ? "Must be the same" : "");
      });
    }
  };
});
```

html:

```
<form name="register">
  <div style="margin-bottom: 10px">
    <input placeholder="password"
      ng-model="newuser.password" type="password" required />
  </div>
  <div style="margin-bottom: 10px">
    <input placeholder="password repeat"
      ng-model="newuser2.password" type="password" required same />
  </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, the script uses the outside AngularJS function setCustomValidity.

It seems like the custom validity message is never cleared (set to empty string) by AngularJS and my parser do not get the chance to run when previous validations fails.

Comment: You're mixing browser's native validation with angular validation. Add the `novalidate` attribute to your form like so: `<form name="register" novalidate>`, then try to debug again.

Comment: But angular makes use of the browsers native validation?

Comment: There can be many conflicts when using both angular and native browser validation, especially when there are complex validation rules in place. I prefer setting 'novalidate' and using `ngMessages` for visual feedback. It seems that my comment tried to steer you to a different direction from what you're trying to achieve, so apologies for that.

Comment: Apologies not needed. The problems with ngMessage is that I have not found a way to set validation messages inside those balloons with it.

Comment: Yes that sounds tricky, and also keep in mind that different browsers are not too consistent with html5 validation. Here's a link to a very useful post regarding angular validation, maybe you can find something that helps you: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html